# Trying to fade and slide text out of initials on mouse over with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an effect with jQuery where on mouse over of my initials on the page in the header, the div they are in expands (using jQuery animate) and the text of my full name fades in from each initial.

I have tried a variety of things but am not sure what is the best way to do this. I'm a bit stuck. I'm currently trying to get it going by having the initials of my name "OW" in two separate divs and then the remainder of my name to make up "wen" and "illiams" in between those initals. Like so:

```
    <div class="initialF inlinediv">O</div>
    <div class="fullF inlinediv">wen</div>
    <div class="initialL inlinediv">W</div>
    <div class="fullL inlinediv">illiams</div>
```

I thought it would work to use jQuery slideLeft and .fadeIn to get the text to slide in from the left as well as fading to look like the text is emerging from the initials but the animations was jumpy and would go onto a second line while the div was still expanding. I am using the below jQuery to detect the mouseIn/Out events:

```
<script>
$(".brand").mouseenter(function() {
$('.brand').animate({width: '160px'});
$('.fullF').fadeIn("slow");
});

$(".brand").mouseout(function() {
$('.brand').animate({width: '36px'});
$('.fullF').fadeOut("slow");
});
</script>
```

The alternatives I have tried were using jquery.lettering.js to help with it but there seemed to be some issues with that. Any suggestions to push me in the right direction would be useful and my site with a partially working example is here:

```
http://192.241.203.146/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to go about this is to just expand the use of your call to the animation method by adding another property to the object you are passing in. So instead of calling an extra method (fadeIn) you just handle it all in one fell swoop:

```
$('.brand').on({
  'mouseenter' : function () {
    $('.nameFull').stop().animate({
      'width' : '200px',
      'opacity' : '1'
    }, 500);
  },
  'mouseleave' : function () {
    $('.nameFull').stop().animate({
      'width' : '0',
      'opacity' : '0'
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

You'll notice I'm also using 'on' instead of the 'hover' or 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' methods. In most recent versions of jQuery those methods just reference 'on', so it's better to just cut out the middle man and do it all in one place.

I'm not sure if this exactly fits your design, but I made a Codepen to demonstrate the code in action: http://codepen.io/Tristan-zimmerman/pen/lnDGh

Comment: +1 for the good idea, make them in one line, it becomes the best answer if the OP wants an animation at the same time with fading.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I love it - that's perfect I think. Would it be possible for it to work as a full name on one line while still retaining the expanding text/fade in? I messed around with display: inline in your example but couldn't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Actually, I've implemented it on my site and the problem I am having is that it's actually already showing the full name until I mouse over and then it compacts. Why would it do that? Your example doesn't seem to :(

Comment: add `.nameFull { width:0; opacity:0; }` to your css

Comment: Oh, I thought I had missed something obvious, thank you for pointing that out. My other problem is that because the namefull width applies to both the first and last names it doesn't properly expand the parent div to the right width, it just overflows outside of it. I suspect to fix it I'll need to separate out the first name - You can see what I mean here: http://192.241.203.146/

Comment: well. we have to leave you with _something_ to do. looks like an easy fix

Comment: A difficulty in jQuery width/height animation is that you can't animate to 'auto'--it needs to have definitive values to use (such as 0 -> 200). I think this makes inline animation a bit more complicated since you want the boxes to be _just_ the right size.

I've used Darcy Clarke's plugin that let's you animate to auto with great success, but it may take some CSS juggling to get accurate measurements: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/animate-heightwidth-to-auto/

Answer (score 4):

Here's one using css transitions rather than jquery animate: http://jsfiddle.net/S58Se/2/

```
<div class='branding'>    
    <span class='initial'>O</span><span class='hidden nameFull wen'>wen</span>
    <span class='initial'>W</span><span class='hidden nameFull illiams'>illiams</span>
</div>

span {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}

.wen { width: 36px; }
.illiams { width: 160px; }

span.hidden {
    width: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
}

$('.branding').hover( 
    function() { $('.nameFull').removeClass('hidden'); },
    function() { $('.nameFull').addClass('hidden'); }
);
```

Or you can do away with the javascript altogether with this: http://jsfiddle.net/S58Se/3/
remove the js and add these css statements:

```
.branding:hover .wen {
    width: 36px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.branding:hover .illiams {
    width: 160px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

... just because I think it's neat.

Comment: It seems much smoother but I wonder how much browser support there would be?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/css-transitions ... it's always IE, but at least transitions degrade gracefully, as it's just a class or css property change

Comment: Seems fair. My only problem with this is that it doesn't expand both at the same time on hover of one initial - is that possible? From what I understand of CSS3 it seems like your code should allow for that.

Answer (score 2):

Style the hidden divs `position:absolute`, and when show them:

1. 'show' them first, to set them visible
2. then position them (next to your 'launching' div),  using jQuery.position();
3. set the animation going.

Essentially you want them 'absolute' to avoid them thunking in/out & changing your existing flow. `position()` must be called after making the element visible, and then you should have appropriate starting conditions to kick off your animation.

Or you could try using `<span>'` for the incoming text and/or displaying as `inline-block`, which may help avoid the "incoming" kicking things down a line. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is something like this: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/4LReS/1/)**

html:

```
<div class="brand">
<div>O<span class="full">wen </span>W<span class="full">illiams</span></div>
</div>
```

jq:

```
$('.brand').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({width: '160px'},'slow',function(){
        $(this).children('div').children('.full').stop().fadeIn('slow');
    }); 
},function(){
    $(this).children('div').children('.full').stop().fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().stop().animate({width: '36px'},'slow');
    });
});
```

css:

```
.full{
    display: none;
}
```

note: there is a simple bug that happens in a specific case and I'm working on it.

regards,